# How can I fix a Javascript Carousel left control that does not working?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on my own to create a post css stype for a blogspot.com template that I purchased recently. With so many tutorials, I made exactly what I want, but the carousel have the issue that does not properly with the left control. Can you help me?

I was searching on YouTube. Most of the code is a modification from something of someone else (I'm a Graphic Designer who barely know the basics of HTML).

Thanks a lot!

```js
  const carousel2 = document.querySelector('.carousel2');
  const slider2 = document.querySelector('.slider2');

  const next = document.querySelector('.next');
  const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
  let direction;

  next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    direction = -1;
    carousel2.style.justifyContent = 'flex-start';
    slider2.style.transform = 'translate(-20%)';  
  });

  prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (direction === -1) {
      direction = 1;
      slider2.appendChild(slider2.firstElementChild);
    }
    carousel2.style.justifyContent = 'flex-end';    
    slider2.style.transform = 'translate(20%)';  
    
  });

  slider2.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    // get the last element and append it to the front
    
    if (direction === 1) {
      slider2.prepend(slider2.lastElementChild);
    } else {
      slider2.appendChild(slider2.firstElementChild);
    }
    
    slider2.style.transition = 'none';
    slider2.style.transform = 'translate(0)';
    setTimeout(() => {
      slider2.style.transition = 'all 0.5s';
    })
  }, false);
```

```css
/*----------POST CAROUSEL SLIDER------------
---------------------------------------------------*/

.carousel-general-container {
  max-width: 780px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/*--POST CAROUSEL 2--*/

.slider-container2 {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.carousel2 {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.slider2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;

}
.slider2 div {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.slider2 div img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.controls2 button.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
}
.controls2 button.prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
}
.controls2 button i {
  font-size: 40px;
}

     
/*---------------------------------------------END--*/
```

```html
<!--POST CAROUSEL CONTAINER-->
<div class="carousel-general-container">
  <!--POST CAROUSEL SLIDER 2-->
  <div class="slider-container2">
    <div class="carousel2">
      <div class="slider2">
        <div>
            <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-u0J4VE6mIeA/XyOZayGTTAI/AAAAAAAAHjc/UWqc7cn13CU4lsoQ6YXtJTu0FCmbGxuKACPcBGAYYCw/s1024/Templates-para-LIBROS.jpg">
        </div>

        <div>
            <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ujMXEoNvpA0/XyXhGwza0YI/AAAAAAAAHkM/NGONl1zblm0ufze1a0DLoCdKSCY_dbgxgCPcBGAYYCw/s1000/graffiti2.jpeg">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="controls2">
        <button class="next"><i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></button>
        <button class="prev"><i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i></button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This is the codepen.](https://codepen.io/kinkimena/pen/gOrRNxV)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, the first thing I see is that when you change the `flex` property of the carrousel2 `justify-content` to `flex-end` you are moving the slider out of the viewport. If you remove that line you solve the issue of not showing anything but the animations do not work as I think you would desire

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I can see it working, but with a white transition. :(

Comment: That new issue is related to the way the browser compiles. It first animates and then paints new created components, such as the appended or preppended elements

Answer (score 1):

why don't You use an already existing **carousel prefab?**
Doing a carousel yourself might teach You a lot of things but It will take a lot of your time!
I personally reccomend You [**Slick.js**](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)!

It is fully personalizable and It is compatible with both desktops and mobiles.
Here is a [quick tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hzIwvuSXpc) on how to set It up ;)

Comment: You should probably add in more details .